# GetWindowDC works not correctly

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I am running the code sample in Charles Petzold's "Programming Windows" book, the "Bitmaps and BitBlts" chapter. The program is supposed to display the `IDI_INFORMATION` icon on the left top corner of the program window on its client area multiple times. But it seems like there are some problems with the `GetWindowDC()` function, because the program display some area outside its entire window instead. Can someone help please? Sorry if my English were bad.

```c
/*−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
BITBLT.C −− BitBlt Demonstration
(c) Charles Petzold, 1998
−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−*/
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName [] = TEXT ("BitBlt") ;

    HWND hwnd ;
    MSG msg ;
    WNDCLASS wndclass ;

    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc ;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0 ;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0 ;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance ;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_INFORMATION) ;
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL ;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

    if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"),
        szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
        return 0 ;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, TEXT ("BitBlt Demo"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL) ;

    ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
    UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
        DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
    }

    return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int cxClient, cyClient, cxSource, cySource ;

    HDC hdcClient, hdcWindow ;
    int x, y ;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps ;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            cxSource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZE) ;
            cySource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYCAPTION) ;
            return 0 ;

        case WM_SIZE:
            cxClient = LOWORD (lParam) ;
            cyClient = HIWORD (lParam) ;
            return 0 ;

        case WM_PAINT:
            hdcClient = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
            hdcWindow = GetWindowDC (hwnd) ;
            for (y = 0 ; y < cyClient ; y += cySource)
                for (x = 0 ; x < cxClient ; x += cxSource)
                {
                    BitBlt (hdcClient, x, y, cxSource, cySource, hdcWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) ;
                }
            ReleaseDC (hwnd, hdcWindow) ;
            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
            return 0 ;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0) ;
            return 0 ;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

[This is the link to the program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fCzA.jpg)

Comment: Since you want to draw in the window's *client area*, you should use `GetDC()` instead, or better the `HDC` returned by `BeginPaint()`. Don't use `GetWindowDC()` unless you intend to draw in the window's *non-client* area

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want to copy the icon from the top left corner of the window (non-client area) . That's why I use GetWindowDC because it retrieves the DC for the entire window. But I don't understand why BitBlt copies from outside the window. Or can you suggest another way to deal with it?

Comment: Assume most people don't have "Programming Windows" to look at (I don't). What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Why are you copying portions of the non-client area into the client area? And why are you using system metrics to calculate what to copy? Window frames are complex things. If you just want the window's icon, look at using [`WM_GETICON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-geticon), and then you can do whatever you want with it. Or, since you are already retrieving the icon with `LoadIcon()`, just hold on to the `HICON` that is given to you.

Comment: The code was written in a time when things were simple. System metrics were accurate, and so were window sizes and positions. Things have changed since, and none of the aforementioned are reliable. `GetWindowDC()` still works as it used to, so this is not the issue. The problem is most likely related to some sort of virtualization, e.g. when a program isn't DPI-aware. It would probably help if you could post a screenshot of the results you are observing.

Comment: @IInspectable I have added the screenshot. Can you please explain for me why it displays the .cpp part instead of the "i" icon?